# Problem with the use of facet_nested for line plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, line-plot

I am trying to plot a line graph with facet nested (I often do that with bar plots). For some strange reason, one part of the plot is missing. I have worked around the code trying to add "group" to the aesthetics but it doesn't seem to work. Below is the graph I am ending up with

I am trying to plot a line graph with facet nested (I often do that with bar plots). For some strange reason, one part of the plot is missing. I have worked around the code trying to add "group" to the aesthetics but it doesn't seem to work. Below is the graph I am ending up with

[image]

```
data10 <- structure(list(Group = c("Visible", "Visible", "Visible", "Visible", 
"Visible", "Visible", "Visible", "Visible", "Visible", "Visible", 
"Visible", "Visible", "Remembered", "Remembered", "Remembered", 
"Remembered", "Remembered", "Remembered", "Remembered", "Remembered", 
"Remembered", "Remembered", "Remembered", "Remembered", "Visible", 
"Visible", "Visible", "Visible", "Visible", "Visible", "Visible", 
"Visible", "Visible", "Visible", "Visible", "Visible", "Remembered", 
"Remembered", "Remembered", "Remembered", "Remembered", "Remembered", 
"Remembered", "Remembered", "Remembered", "Remembered", "Remembered", 
"Remembered"), Condition = c("CEN", "CEN", "CEN", "CEN", "IPS", 
"IPS", "IPS", "IPS", "CTL", "CTL", "CTL", "CTL", "CEN", "CEN", 
"CEN", "CEN", "IPS", "IPS", "IPS", "IPS", "CTL", "CTL", "CTL", 
"CTL", "CEN", "CEN", "CEN", "CEN", "IPS", "IPS", "IPS", "IPS", 
"CTL", "CTL", "CTL", "CTL", "CEN", "CEN", "CEN", "CEN", "IPS", 
"IPS", "IPS", "IPS", "CTL", "CTL", "CTL", "CTL"), test1 = c("Pre-test", 
"Pre-test", "Post-test", "Post-test", "Pre-test", "Pre-test", 
"Post-test", "Post-test", "Pre-test", "Pre-test", "Post-test", 
"Post-test", "Pre-test", "Pre-test", "Post-test", "Post-test", 
"Pre-test", "Pre-test", "Post-test", "Post-test", "Pre-test", 
"Pre-test", "Post-test", "Post-test", "Pre-test", "Pre-test", 
"Post-test", "Post-test", "Pre-test", "Pre-test", "Post-test", 
"Post-test", "Pre-test", "Pre-test", "Post-test", "Post-test", 
"Pre-test", "Pre-test", "Post-test", "Post-test", "Pre-test", 
"Pre-test", "Post-test", "Post-test", "Pre-test", "Pre-test", 
"Post-test", "Post-test"), test = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Pre-test", 
"Post-test"), class = "factor"), trial2 = c(1, 5, 9, 13, 1, 5, 
9, 13, 1, 5, 9, 13, 1, 5, 9, 13, 1, 5, 9, 13, 1, 5, 9, 13, 1, 
5, 9, 13, 1, 5, 9, 13, 1, 5, 9, 13, 1, 5, 9, 13, 1, 5, 9, 13, 
1, 5, 9, 13), trial = c("Pre-1", "Pre-5", "Post-1", "Post-5", 
"Pre-1", "Pre-5", "Post-1", "Post-5", "Pre-1", "Pre-5", "Post-1", 
"Post-5", "Pre-1", "Pre-5", "Post-1", "Post-5", "Pre-1", "Pre-5", 
"Post-1", "Post-5", "Pre-1", "Pre-5", "Post-1", "Post-5", "Pre-1", 
"Pre-5", "Post-1", "Post-5", "Pre-1", "Pre-5", "Post-1", "Post-5", 
"Pre-1", "Pre-5", "Post-1", "Post-5", "Pre-1", "Pre-5", "Post-1", 
"Post-5", "Pre-1", "Pre-5", "Post-1", "Post-5", "Pre-1", "Pre-5", 
"Post-1", "Post-5"), N = c(12, 10, 12, 11, 11, 9, 12, 12, 12, 
10, 12, 12, 9, 11, 12, 12, 8, 12, 11, 12, 9, 9, 12, 12, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Variables = c("Eye reaction time", "Eye reaction time", 
"Eye reaction time", "Eye reaction time", "Eye reaction time", 
"Eye reaction time", "Eye reaction time", "Eye reaction time", 
"Eye reaction time", "Eye reaction time", "Eye reaction time", 
"Eye reaction time", "Eye reaction time", "Eye reaction time", 
"Eye reaction time", "Eye reaction time", "Eye reaction time", 
"Eye reaction time", "Eye reaction time", "Eye reaction time", 
"Eye reaction time", "Eye reaction time", "Eye reaction time", 
"Eye reaction time", "Hand reaction time", "Hand reaction time", 
"Hand reaction time", "Hand reaction time", "Hand reaction time", 
"Hand reaction time", "Hand reaction time", "Hand reaction time", 
"Hand reaction time", "Hand reaction time", "Hand reaction time", 
"Hand reaction time", "Hand reaction time", "Hand reaction time", 
"Hand reaction time", "Hand reaction time", "Hand reaction time", 
"Hand reaction time", "Hand reaction time", "Hand reaction time", 
"Hand reaction time", "Hand reaction time", "Hand reaction time", 
"Hand reaction time"), Eye_Rx = c(0.190333333, 0.213909091, 0.164583333, 
0.2375, 0.24375, 0.215444444, 0.168916667, 0.259916667, 0.147333333, 
0.277363636, 0.20425, 0.240833333, 0.189222222, 0.146727273, 
0.111083333, 0.13225, 0.183375, 0.166583333, 0.115727273, 0.14, 
0.15, 0.222222222, 0.206916667, 0.133083333, 0.423583333, 0.507636364, 
0.374083333, 0.399166667, 0.45075, 0.401333333, 0.411583333, 
0.459083333, 0.411166667, 0.433727273, 0.380333333, 0.4115, 0.411555556, 
0.420636364, 0.294416667, 0.29875, 0.40425, 0.405833333, 0.330818182, 
0.318, 0.353666667, 0.366555556, 0.338666667, 0.319333333), sd = c(0.113040084, 
0.120666859, 0.093087894, 0.149627112, 0.164622502, 0.099557912, 
0.058356987, 0.323980207, 0.094897393, 0.27273697, 0.199661589, 
0.16341238, 0.143796538, 0.069264841, 0.03580873, 0.041850654, 
0.155523023, 0.091204524, 0.065353027, 0.077994172, 0.098432718, 
0.173048965, 0.179821861, 0.063938121, 0.138244486, 0.398595854, 
0.107139211, 0.19240149, 0.296251467, 0.188482095, 0.183202054, 
0.232274703, 0.155725769, 0.181612274, 0.135318032, 0.165268652, 
0.169866941, 0.189299906, 0.071530614, 0.049045665, 0.117074762, 
0.100927367, 0.090403339, 0.060077223, 0.073431941, 0.045735957, 
0.208057393, 0.068832251), se = c(0.032631861, 0.036382427, 0.02687216, 
0.043193627, 0.047522423, 0.033185971, 0.016846211, 0.09352503, 
0.027394518, 0.08223329, 0.057637336, 0.047173091, 0.047932179, 
0.020884135, 0.01033709, 0.012081243, 0.054985692, 0.026328478, 
0.019704679, 0.022514978, 0.032810906, 0.057682988, 0.0519101, 
0.018457346, 0.039907746, 0.120181172, 0.030928426, 0.055541526, 
0.085520432, 0.062827365, 0.052885877, 0.067051931, 0.044954157, 
0.054758161, 0.039062951, 0.04770895, 0.056622314, 0.057076069, 
0.02064911, 0.014158264, 0.041392179, 0.029135221, 0.027257632, 
0.0173428, 0.024477314, 0.015245319, 0.060060996, 0.019870159
), ci = c(0.071822243, 0.081065099, 0.059145226, 0.095068532, 
0.104596148, 0.076526985, 0.03707826, 0.205847203, 0.060294927, 
0.183227189, 0.126858921, 0.103827273, 0.110531804, 0.046532753, 
0.022751782, 0.026590637, 0.130020501, 0.05794859, 0.043904761, 
0.049555133, 0.075662085, 0.13301721, 0.114253359, 0.040624344, 
0.087836356, 0.267780338, 0.068073007, 0.122246075, 0.188229202, 
0.144880163, 0.116401031, 0.147580306, 0.098943433, 0.122008786, 
0.085976975, 0.105006692, 0.13057129, 0.127173408, 0.045448384, 
0.031162129, 0.097876951, 0.064126189, 0.060733789, 0.038171246, 
0.056444787, 0.035155769, 0.132193361, 0.043733926)), row.names = c(NA, 
-48L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(Group = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Condition = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), test1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), test = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), trial2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), trial = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), N = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Variables = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Eye_Rx = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), sd = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), se = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), ci = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
library(ggh4x)


 p <- ggplot(data10, aes(x = trial2, y = Eye_Rx),group = test) + 
   geom_line(aes(color = Variables), lwd=1.2, show.legend = F) + 
   geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = Eye_Rx - 1.96 * se, ymax = Eye_Rx + 1.96 * se, fill = Variables), alpha = .6) +
   scale_fill_manual(values = c("gray", "black"))+  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "gray")) + facet_nested(Condition ~ Group + test)+ theme_bw() + xlab("Trial") + ylab("Hand and Eye Reaction time (s)") +
   scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1,8), breaks = seq(1,8,1),labels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8")) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12,face="bold", angle = 90),#, angle = 10, hjust = .5, vjust = .5),
                                                                                                                                                                 axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),
                                                                                                                                                                 axis.title.y = element_text(vjust= 1.8, size = 18),
                                                                                                                                                                 axis.title.x = element_text(vjust= -0.5, size = 18),
                                                                                                                                                                 axis.title = element_text(face = "bold")) +  theme(legend.position="top") +
   guides(fill=guide_legend(title="")) + theme(legend.text=element_text(size=16),legend.title=element_text(size=14) ) +
   theme(strip.text = element_text(face="bold", size=16)) 
 p
```

Comment: The same happens if you replace `facet_nested()` with `facet_grid()`. The issue seems to be the x-axis limits that exclude your 'post-test' panels.

Comment: At what point would you decide to add a [ggh4x] tag on SO @teunbrand? Or would you wait for someone else to do it?

Comment: Hahaha, I'm not quite sure my little package of ggplot tricks merits its own SO tag :p

Answer (score 2):

You are excluding all of your `post-test` results because these all have x axis values of 9 or more. Remove the `scale_x_continuous` and add `scales = "free_x"` to `facet_nested`

```r
ggplot(data10, aes(x = trial2, y = Eye_Rx),group = test) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = Variables), lwd = 1.2, show.legend = FALSE) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = Eye_Rx - 1.96 * se, ymax = Eye_Rx + 1.96 * se, 
                 fill = Variables), alpha = 0.6) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("gray", "black"), name = NULL) +  
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "gray")) + 
  xlab("Trial") + 
  ylab("Hand and Eye Reaction time (s)") +
  facet_nested(Condition ~ Group + test, scales = "free_x") +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12,face="bold", angle = 90),
       axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),
       axis.title.y = element_text(vjust= 1.8, size = 18),
       axis.title.x = element_text(vjust= -0.5, size = 18),
       axis.title = element_text(face = "bold"),
       legend.position = "top",
       legend.text = element_text(size = 16),
       legend.title = element_text(size = 14),
       strip.text = element_text(face = "bold", size = 16))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with the x axis limits.

Modifying extending the limits give this:

```
ggplot(data10, aes(x = trial2, y = Eye_Rx),group = test) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = Variables), lwd=1.2, show.legend = F) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = Eye_Rx - 1.96 * se, ymax = Eye_Rx + 1.96 * se, fill = Variables), alpha = .6) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("gray", "black"))+  
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "gray")) + 
  facet_nested(Condition ~ Group + test, scales = "free")+ theme_bw() + 
  xlab("Trial") + ylab("Hand and Eye Reaction time (s)") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1,13), breaks = seq(1,13,1),
                     labels = as.character(1:13)) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12,face="bold", angle = 90),#, angle = 10, hjust = .5, vjust = .5),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(vjust= 1.8, size = 18),
        axis.title.x = element_text(vjust= -0.5, size = 18),
        axis.title = element_text(face = "bold")) +  theme(legend.position="top") +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="")) + 
  theme(legend.text=element_text(size=16),legend.title=element_text(size=14) ) +
  theme(strip.text = element_text(face="bold", size=16))
```

[image]

Removing the limits and making the scale = "free", gives this:

```
ggplot(data10, aes(x = trial2, y = Eye_Rx),group = test) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = Variables), lwd=1.2, show.legend = F) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = Eye_Rx - 1.96 * se, ymax = Eye_Rx + 1.96 * se, fill = Variables), alpha = .6) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("gray", "black"))+  
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "gray")) + 
  facet_nested(Condition ~ Group + test, scales = "free")+ theme_bw() + 
  xlab("Trial") + ylab("Hand and Eye Reaction time (s)")  + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12,face="bold", angle = 90),#, angle = 10, hjust = .5, vjust = .5),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(vjust= 1.8, size = 18),
        axis.title.x = element_text(vjust= -0.5, size = 18),
        axis.title = element_text(face = "bold")) +  theme(legend.position="top") +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="")) + 
  theme(legend.text=element_text(size=16),legend.title=element_text(size=14) ) +
  theme(strip.text = element_text(face="bold", size=16))
```

[image]

Comment: I am wondering if there is a way to edit the xticks, I was hoping I could repeat the numbers for "Pre-test" and "Post-test"